# Netsuite 2.0 Serch filter for SalesOrders that are from WEB store

Tags: netsuite

Trying to get Sales order that are maded from SCA (Suite commerce advanced) here is my code.

```
var type = searchModule.Type.SALES_ORDER;
    var columns = [];
    var filters = [];
    columns = _.concat(columns, [
        searchModule.createColumn({
            name: 'internalid'
        }),
        searchModule.createColumn({
            name: 'tranid'
        })
    ]);

    filters = _.concat(filters, [
        searchModule.createFilter({
            name: 'status',
            operator: searchModule.Operator.IS,
            values: 'SalesOrd:A'
        }),
        searchModule.createFilter({
            name: 'mainline',
            operator: searchModule.Operator.IS,
            values: 'T'
        }),
        searchModule.createFilter({
            name: 'type',
            operator: searchModule.Operator.ANYOF,
            values: 'SalesOrd'
        }),
        searchModule.createFilter({
            name: 'source',
            operator: searchModule.Operator.STARTSWITH,
            values: 'Web'
        })
    ]);

    var mySearchObj = {type: type, filters: filters, columns: columns};
    // uncomment for test use
    /*
    log.debug({title: 'type', details: type});
    log.debug({title: 'columns', details: columns});
    log.debug({title: 'filters', details: filters});
    */
    var searchItems = searchModule.create(mySearchObj).run().getRange({start: 0, end: 999});
    ordersList = [];
```

the filter that is not working

```
        searchModule.createFilter({
            name: 'source',
            operator: searchModule.Operator.STARTSWITH,
            values: 'Web'
        })
```

its there any way to get this work, i tried with CONTAINS also and the same problem not working. launch and SC exeptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ANYOF` as operator instead `STARTSWITH`

```
        searchModule.createFilter({
            name: 'source',
            operator: searchModule.Operator.ANYOF,
            values: ['WebStore Name']
        })
```

Here is an extract of a working saved search with source field used as filter.

```
{  
      "name":"source",
      "join":null,
      "operator":"anyof",
      "values":[  
         "NLWebStore"
      ],
      "formula":null,
      "summarytype":null,
      "isor":false,
      "isnot":false,
      "leftparens":0,
      "rightparens":0
   }
```

Comment: Thx for your share, as we use 5 SCA, the search conditions meet the necesary. thx for your  response.

Answer (score 1):

The `source` Filter has a Field Type of `Select`, which means you cannot use text operators on it. The only operators you can use are `ANYOF` and `NONEOF`. You will want to find the Internal ID of the SCA value for Source and use that for your Filter value instead.

I'm unsure where that ID can be found, but you can find it by loading a Sales Order that has the appropriate value set in its Source field and using `getValue()` to see what that value is.